# Why is there no word for and/or?

Tags: terminology, logic

It seems like it would be really useful to have a single word like "anor" instead of the clunky "and/or" construction that people use. After all, "or" by itself is usually used to mean "exclusive or" in English.

> I would like to visit the circus *anor* the museum today.

versus

> I would like to visit the circus *and/or* the museum today.

Comment: Actually "or" means either "and/or" or "xor". People say "and/or" to clarify that they do not mean "xor".

Comment: There is, and the word is "[and/or](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and/or)". Words are allowed to have punctuation in them.

Comment: I suppose the fact that we *don't* have such a word might suggest *we don't really need one*. On the relatively few occasions when it's important to distinguish the logic operators OR and XOR, we can always just use *and/or* anyway, as phenry says.

Comment: or better yet, just append "or both" rather than that word-glob "and/or".

Comment: Right; I just hate the forward slash here because it's a punctuation mark that's really a short form for "or" itself. So "and/or" becomes "and or or". Should we really have to say "and or or" to mean the basic logical operator OR?

Answer (score 4):

> After all, "or" by itself is usually used to mean "exclusive or" in English.

No, it isn't.  None of [several](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/or?s=t) [common](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/OR) [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Or) [sources](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or) support the reading that "or" is usually an exclusive choice in written or spoken English.  I'll quote the first:

> **OR** —used as a function word to indicate an alternative (coffee or tea) (sink or swim), the equivalent or substitutive character of two words or phrases (lessen or abate), or approximation or uncertainty (in five or six days)

In most cases, the language requires you to infer the exclusiviity of the choice based on context.

Should you need to offer someone an exclusive choice, or wish to minimize the chance of confusion, the solution is to use more of our existing words rather than attempting to coin another.

> I would you like either coffee or tea with your dinner?
>
> You may pay your bill by either check, cash, credit card, or a combination of all three.

Comment: But all of those examples are either exclusive alternatives (sink or swim, five or six days) or something other than the logical operator OR (e.g. "... lessen, or abate, ..." which is clarification by providing an equivalent substitute).

Comment: they aren't exclusive unless context requires them to be.  "the recruits will sink or swim" allows for some to sink, some to swim, and even for some to do both.